# PHP and Python Requests

Tags: php, python, python-requests

I have a python script which runs fine at a linux command line.  When I try to call it from inside a PHP page, the script stops at the get request.  Honestly there is probably a better why to integrate python scripts within webpages (feel free to direct me to a resource to help get me started here).  However for now, I am trying to get this script to work.  If I place print statements before the get, they print.  However, no print statements work after the get.

The python script doesn't expect anything when it is called, I just removed the user and password from the script.

Here is what is returned when I run it from a command line:

```
$ python test.py
(u'172.18.251.225', u'25502760-d9a5-11e6-80af-00505684337f', u'MNIT LAN Device')
$
```

Here is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin python

import json
import requests

ERSUser = 'user'
ERSPassword = 'pass'

s = requests.session()
s.auth = (ERSUser, ERSPassword)
s.verify = True
s.headers.update({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Connection': 'keep_alive',
            'Content_type': 'application/json'
            })
url = "https://www.myserver.com:9060/ers/config/networkdevicefilter=ipaddress.EQ.172.18.251.225"

r = s.get(url)

for i in r.json()['SearchResult']['resources']:
       print (i['name'], i['id'], i['description'])
```

Here is the part of the php where I call the test.py script:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python /var/www/cgi-bin/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Here is from my Apache log:

```
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 - Permission denied (13)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    r = s.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 476, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
[dsampson@mnet-ws-dave httpd]$
```

Comment: Your python script expects stuff in an http request, which you're not providing in your php script. You're just calling the script from the command line. For example, what do you expect `request.session()` to return?

Comment: Added responses to your questions Federico in my initial post

Comment: Your request seems simple enough. Why don't you use `curl` (I mean PHP curl) or `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Just throwing stuff against the wall: could it be that your shell has some proxy set so that the request goes through it when you run it from the command line and not when you run it via web?